# What is fatwire from programmer perspective?

Tags: content-management, fatwire

What open source toolkit does fatwire compare to and are there some particular advantages to fatwire?

How hard is fatwire to export out of and move to a free alternative?

How stable is it as a platform to write java extensions on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a development persepective, FatWire can be unfriendly.  Having worked on a number of sites using this application it can easy bloat, and become difficult to maintain.

From a user perspective there has been alot of effort in the UI and this has led to a highly functional tool.

From a client perspective all clients bar 1 (a large news agency) were happy with the end result.  FatWire can slow when using complex logic to generate menus or breadcumbs for example or when you have a large amount of content.  This is the main reason the one client was unhappy.  The FatWire site regularily struggled under the load.  It sometimes seen as a solution to all web needs.

As such FatWire succeeds in serving Static Content & Semi Dynamic content, but can flounder when forced to do fully dynamic sites (from my experience).

Answer (score 5):

From the original press release:

> FatWire Software announced the rollout
>   of FirstSite, which is a set of tools
>   and best practices that helps
>   companies using FatWire Content Server
>   get their first Web site or
>   application running quickly while
>   providing a foundation for future
>   expansion. FirstSite includes a
>   collection of standard templates and
>   site components that are common to
>   most sites, combined with
>   documentation, training, a rich
>   developer community, and best
>   practices methodology. FatWire and its
>   solution partners are using FirstSite
>   as the basis for developing
>   content-centric applications for
>   specific vertical markets. With only
>   minor, cosmetic alterations,
>   developers can use the code in
>   FirstSite to implement a first site,
>   while simultaneously learning how to
>   utilize Content Server's capabilities,
>   such as dynamic content delivery,
>   personalization, caching, and product
>   catalogs.

Firstsite is not a product, unless this has changed since 2004 (unfortunately I cannot look, since their developer site is down). Fatwire's Content Server does not compare to any Open Source CMS that I know. It's scope goes much further. I will answer your questions one by one:

**Advantages** - There are many (or nobody would buy it, and it is not cheap)

On the delivery side: scalability, fine-grained cache control, stateless servlet architecture, ....

On the back office side: virtually no limit to asset types, dynamic content attributes, find-grained security and access control, ...

On the development side: Intelligently architected API with good coding productivity, tag library, ...

**Openness**

You cannot easily expect to migrate content between any two CMS products, open source or not. While there are ways to extract contant from the database in XML and other forms, using product tools, or simply at the database level, I don't think that this can be an argument for or against using a particular CMS. Ever tried to migrate from Drupal to Joomla?

**Stable**

I worked on several Fatwire implementations from 2000 to 2004 (back then it was OpenMarket Content Server, then Divine Content Server). It was stable enough for the Washington Post, the New York Times, and the S&P sites, and I would expect stability not to be an issue today.

Comment: "(unfortunately I cannot look, since their developer site is down)" Is this indications of the underlying company's stability?

Comment: I remove "firstsite " from title since its irrelevant

Answer (score 4):

Fatwire is really unique concept from developer point of view. It builds everything on a very abstract, extremely flexible clever asset modeling framework which is stored in relational database.

Application logic is based on "templates" which actually are pieces of JSP code. This JSP code is not like conventional Java, but tags instead. It takes very long from a developer to learn these tags and Fatwire asset api. Expect even months before skilled develpers start to be productive.

Almost nothing useable samples ships along the product. There is advertized "FirstSite" but it is way too simple for the purpose this product is used normally (huge complex sites). So pretty much everything has to be built from scratch.

Cache control is advertized to be one powerful feature. Yes it is, but we had extremely long learning curve and it never worked exactly like one assumed.

Wysiwyg editing has been missed from this product even it is advertized. At least during 2009 it had serious conceptual problems which practically prevented using it in live environments. But it was cool feature for demos and marketing of course. Today it might be fixed.

As a summary and if I were a customer with limited budget, I'd select any open source alternative instead. Mostly because development costs with Fatwire are high due the uniqueness of the product, lack of good documentation and extremely long learing curve. Of course the product price tag is also thing to consider.

And to answer to questions: you have to start from scratch if you move from Fatwire 6.0 to any open source alternative. And it is stable to build Java extensions on.

Answer (score 0):

Fatwire stores content in relation database and file system. Depending on what type of content (structured/unstructured), Fatwire can be evaluated.